# In .htaccess how to get a particular value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I am trying to get a specific value from url

like my url is

```
http://www.example.biz/?_escaped_fragment=reader/i/1664
```

and I want to get output url is like below

```
http://www.example.biz/seo/1664
```

I have tried this

```
RewriteCond^(.*?)_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ seo/%1 [NC]
```

But Output url is coming below

```
http://www.example.biz/seo/%1?_escaped_fragment=reader/i/1664
```

How will I do this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: try to see this: http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not trying to match *anything* in your `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)_escaped_fragment=reader/i/(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ seo/%1 [L]
```

Comment: @Riturajratan You had an extra `_` after `escaped_fragment`.

Comment: but output url is looking http://www.example.biz/seo/1664?_escaped_fragment=reader/i/1664 
i want http://www.example.biz/seo/1664

Comment: @Riturajratan Use the [`QSD` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) along with `L` one. Thus, it'll be `[L,QSD]`

Comment: when you will try [L,QSD] it will give message 
This rule was met, the new url is http://www.example.biz/seo/1664?_escaped_fragment=reader/i/1664
The tests are stopped because the L in your RewriteRule options

Comment: @Riturajratan Did you try it on your server? Did you read the Apache manual on `QSD` flag?

Comment: i am working in drupal and i have added like that 

 `# Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)_escaped_fragment=reader/i/(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ seo/%1 [L] `

and it give me internal server error